TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')
here is my code please help me
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from '../utils/constants';

export const TransactionContext = React.createContext();
// const ethers = require("ethers");
// const BigNumber  = require("ethers");
const getEthereumContract = async () => {
    let signer = null;
    let provider;

    if (window.ethereum == null) {
        console.log("MetaMask not installed; using read-only defaults");
        provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
    } else {
        provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        signer = await provider.getSigner();
    }

    const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer || provider);

    console.log({
        provider,
        signer,
        transactionContract
    });

    return transactionContract;
}

export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState('');
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ addressTo: '', amount: '', keyword: '', message: '' });

    const handleChange = (e, name) => {
        setFormData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
    }

    const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async () => {
        const { ethereum } = window;
        try {
            if (!ethereum) {
                alert("Please install MetaMask");
                return;
            }

            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
            if (accounts.length) {
                setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
            } else {
                console.log('No accounts found');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error("No Ethereum object.");
        }
    }

    const connectWallet = async () => {
        const { ethereum } = window;
        try {
            if (!ethereum) {
                alert("Please install MetaMask");
                return;
            }

            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error("No Ethereum object.");
        }
    }

    const sendTransaction = async () => {
        try {
            const { ethereum } = window;
            if (!ethereum) {
                alert("Please install MetaMask");
                return;
            }

            const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
            const transactionContract = await getEthereumContract();

            if (transactionContract) {
                const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);

                const transactionParameters = {
                    to: addressTo,
                    from: currentAccount,
                    value: parsedAmount._hex,
                    data: ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(message)
                };

                await ethereum.request({
                    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                    params: [transactionParameters]
                });

                console.log("Transaction sent");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error("No Ethereum object.");
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfWalletIsConnected();
    }, []);

    return (
        <TransactionContext.Provider value={{
            currentAccount,
            connectWallet,
            formData,
            setFormData,
            handleChange,
            sendTransaction
        }}>
            {children}
        </TransactionContext.Provider>
    );
}


Which version of ethers library are you using?

I'm using ether@^5.7.0 and it's continuesly showing error . I've also tried Alchemy Provider but can't resolve the issue .

Can you try to uninstall ethers (using npm uninstall ethers) and reinstall again (using npm install ethers@5.7.2) ?

Thanks that works fine .

Great. Happy coding!
